# Which hindu scripture talks about the astrological remedies as per vedic astrology?

Tags: astrology, navagraha, horary-astrology, planets

What are the Hindu scriptures that talk about different planetary remedies or remedies to particularly malefic yogas such as KalSarpa Yoga and Pitru Dosha Yoga?